# Перекрытие контентом toolbar'а

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

Здравствуйте.
Создал проект на основе NavigationDrawer. При добавлении в основной модуль содержимого с параметрами (`android:layout_heinght="match_parent"` и `android:layout_width="match_parent"`) - оно перекрывает имеющийся toolbar, поэтому на него нельзя нажать и он не функционирует.

Comment: Напиши xml файл, где твой navigationDrawer расположен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась перемещением компанентов внутри `app_bar_main.xml`. Их очередность в файле влияет на отображение. Поэтому перемещение `<include>` выше - исправило ситуацию.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ru.jorik.verst.MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/content_main" /> <!--перемещен сюда-->

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/black"
        >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/customTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!-- include был сдесь-->

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```